# Minimum value of doc topic distribution in scikit-learn's Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, topic-modeling

When extracting 45 topics from a corpus of documents, I get the following result when calling scikit-learn's `LatentDirichletAllocation.transform` method with a `doc_topic_prior` of 0.1:

`array([0.01333382, 0.01333628, 0.01333336, 0.01333731, 0.01333334,
       0.0133361 , 0.01333334, 0.01333475, 0.01333334, 0.01333598,
       0.01333431, 0.01333442, 0.01333334, 0.29496004, 0.01333456,
       0.01333455, 0.01333603, 0.01333335, 0.01333393, 0.01333651,
       0.01333511, 0.01333337, 0.01333518, 0.01333377, 0.01333434,
       0.01333334, 0.01333354, 0.01333538, 0.13166403, 0.01333367,
       0.01333333, 0.01333339, 0.01333356, 0.01333648, 0.01333397,
       0.01333353, 0.01333342, 0.01333707, 0.01333337, 0.01333339,
       0.01333451, 0.01333334, 0.01333352, 0.01333334, 0.01333338])`

It appears that there is an artificial lower limit of about 0.01333 on the doc-topic distribution. Is there a parameter for the `fit` method that can be set to avoid this lower limit? I've tried increasing `max_iter` & `max_doc_update_iter` and lowering `mean_change_tol` but none have any effect. When I set the `doc_topic_prior` to 0.3, I get similar results but with a lower limit around 0.018.

Is there a way to avoid or reduce this lower limit on the doc-topic distribution?

Here is the full set of model parameters for the results above:

`{'batch_size': 128,
 'doc_topic_prior': 0.1,
 'evaluate_every': -1,
 'learning_decay': 0.7,
 'learning_method': 'batch',
 'learning_offset': 10.0,
 'max_doc_update_iter': 100,
 'max_iter': 10,
 'mean_change_tol': 0.001,
 'n_components': 45,
 'n_jobs': -1,
 'n_topics': None,
 'perp_tol': 0.1,
 'random_state': None,
 'topic_word_prior': 0.9,
 'total_samples': 1000000.0,
 'verbose': 0}`